# Ajustando imagens em diferentes telas

Tags: android

Estou rodando o app em dois emuladores que têm exatamente a mesma resolução mas densidades diferentes:

1. 720 x 1280 160dpi
2. 720 x 1280 320dpi

**Quero que a imagem tome o mesmo espaço na tela.**
Eu entendo que, usando DP, a densidade passa a ser indiferente, pois o sistema calcula a quantidade de pixels de acordo com o a densidade e o espaço que a imagem deve ter na tela. No entanto, isso não acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como chegar a esse valor em DP para que uma imagem tome exatamente o mesmo espaço em telas com tamanhos e densidades diferentes?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Poste o xml que está a usar.

Comment: Os emuladores das imagens que postou têm resoluções diferentes.

Comment: Na verdade, eu subi a imagem errada. Eles têm a mesma resolução conforme citei. Vou editar com o XML

Answer (score 2):

Crie imagens com diferentes resoluções e coloque nos respectivos packages, de acordo com a lista abaixo:

- xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960 (320 dpi)
- large (hdpi): 480x800 (240 dpi)
- medium (mdpi): 320x480 (160 dpi)
- small (ldpi): 240x320 (120 dpi)

Link da **[documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)**

Comment: Então, já havia feito isso, mas não chego ao resultado.
Dê uma olhada nesse meu outro post pra ver se entende melhor o problema... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292713/two-screens-same-size-with-different-density?noredirect=1&lq=1